# How to avoid Scrapy url being redirected

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website using scrapy. Sometimes my code is working but sometimes it is not working. The reason my code cannot scrape the web page is because the url gets redirected. For example, I was trying to scrape www.example.com/page=1, which was redirected into www.verify.example.com. It appears to move you into the verify version of the url in order to check that you are a human.  I have tried using proxy with many user-agents but this is not working. I think this was the problem when I was requesting the url.

```
res = scrapy.Request(
url=the_url,
meta={
    "proxy":"https://"+proxy,
}, 
callback=self.next_page
```

The proxy I was getting from some page. Here is the code:

```
def get_proxies(self,empty):
url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
response = requests.get(url)
parser = fromstring(response.text)
list_ip = []
proxies = set()
for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:100]:
    if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
        #Grabbing IP and corresponding PORT
        proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
        proxies.add(proxy)
for loop_proxies in proxies:
    list_ip.append(loop_proxies)

return list_ip
```

I got the "get_proxies" functioning from internet. And in settings.py it was like this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for example project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'example'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['example.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'example.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
# USER_AGENT = 'example (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
LOG_ENABLED = True
# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 4
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}
# DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    # 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36',
    # 'Cookie':'s_ViewType=10; _lxsdk_s=16eb7c37081-08b-750-06a%7C%7C200; _lxsdk_cuid=16eb8d09cf5c8-05ca75fa4b8f66-14291003-100200-16eb8d09cf5c8; _lxsdk=16eb8d09cf5c8-05ca75fa4b8f66-14291003-100200-16eb8d09cf5c8; _hc.v=8f832efa-3775-aeec-1189-37c6d815ecb0.1575058712'
    # 'Cookie':'ALF=1573490222; _T_WM=148616430989eb5a607186e5ccc1bd5a4754b18b318; SCF=AlnIW_LpGKigwbo6ysyWWwVvTa_owlI2qJO_J1CxkMPEGosrBTKlnFR2fkvt82OUSt8ALZaDaUYGDQ9K0TtOAK8.; SUB=_2A25wpnFhDeRhGeFN6loW9CrPyDiIHXVQaR8prDV6PUJbktBeLRahkW1NQEqapQmLSHVEFcFyeIkn1OBaYewoa96T; SUBP=0033WrSXqPxfM725Ws9jqgMF55529P9D9WFEx4XGa4r.ozPRKdw4_Wmx5JpX5K-hUgL.FoM0eKnNShB0e0B2dJLoIpRLxK-LB-BL1KBLxK-LBKBLB-zLxK-LB-BL1K5peo-t; SUHB=0TPVAlkzF8-YRN; SSOLoginState=1570898225; MLOGIN=1; _T_WL=1'
# }

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'example.middlewares.DianpingScrapeSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'example.middlewares.DianpingScrapeDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'example.middlewares.RotateUserAgentMiddleware': 543,
    # 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': None,
    # 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware': None,
}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'example.pipelines.DianpingScrapePipeline': 300,
   # 'example.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware': 700,
}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
# AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [403]
```

And I added a new function inside the middlewares.py to add the user-agent as follows:

```
class RotateUserAgentMiddleware(UserAgentMiddleware):  
    def __init__(self, user_agent=''):  
        self.user_agent = user_agent  

    def process_request(self, request, spider):  
        ua = random.choice(self.user_agent_list)  
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)  

    #the default user_agent_list composes chrome,I E,firefox,Mozilla,opera,netscape  
    #for more user agent strings,you can find it in http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php  
    user_agent_list = [     
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1" 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 2268.111.0) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.0 Safari/536.6", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1090.0 Safari/536.6", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.77.34.5 Safari/537.1", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.9 Safari/536.5", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.36 Safari/536.5", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1063.0 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1063.0 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1063.0 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1062.0 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1062.0 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.0 Safari/536.3", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24"  
       ]
```

And I got different warnings:

```
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.

[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.example.com/>

twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]

Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Crawled 13 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Comment: response never received is usually due to request not having a User Agent,or an error has occurred in the proxy server

Comment: if you use free proxies, lots of people use them and they get banned - this could be the problem.  Using auto-throttling would be an idea to stay under the radar too

Comment: do you mean using ```time.sleep()``` ?
i already use that

Comment: I would experiment with - increasing the download delay, using auto-throttling (it isn't the sleep function, its a feature of settings.py as per your code above), choosing robots_txt_obey = false, and also requests can be set to not redirect